# Error: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896 throw err Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\arij\first'

Tags: node.js

when I try to run my first appliction with node js I get this error:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\arij\first'
and this my code:

```
console.log("hello");
```

Comment: Where is your file located? How are you invoking node? What's our current working directory?

Comment: 1) hi ! I created a new folder on desktop named arij then i open the visual studio code and i imported this folder after that i created a file named first application.js so the file is in the folder arij   2) node js is uploaded from node js.org 3) Desktop